# Variation of Pursuit-evasion (Cops and Robbers)

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I am considering to investigate on a variation of the cops and robber game where the robber is considered as an "invisible evader" for their location is unknown until one of the cops are at an adjacent node to the robber.

I was just wondering whether this has been previously studied by any individuals and if so, how much. It would be really helpful if I can be directed to that study.

Thank you.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that recently I heard a conference talk about this variation, but I failed to find a reference. So if you will not obtain an answer here, I recommend you to ask your question at MathOverflow.

Comment: Sounds similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_the_Wumpus .